# C# DataGridViewComboBoxCell 2 kind of enter ( text and droplist ) when get focus value disappear

Tags: c#, datagridview

My `datagridview` have 6 `comboboxcells`, I would like those `combobox` can key number & select `dropdownlist (On, Off)`. But I found when my `comboboxcell` get focus, the value will disappear. Now I select key text number to `row[0]column[2]`, whenr I finish enter number and use `"Enter"` or `mouse click` to next `row[1]column[2]`, the`row[1]column[2]` get focus, and the value I entered before will disappear. Why `comboxcell` get focus will disappear value?
[text & dropdownlist data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AdFx.png)
[next row get focus , the value disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enwpc.png)
Below are my code :

```
    delegate void SetComboBoxCellType(int iRowIndex);
    bool bIsComboBox = false;

    private void datagridview_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            SetComboBoxCellType objChangeCellType = new SetComboBoxCellType(ChangeCellToComboBox);

            if (e.ColumnIndex == this.datagridview.Columns[2].Index)   
            {
                if (datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Controlword")
                {
                    this.datagridview.BeginInvoke(objChangeCellType, e.RowIndex);
                    bIsComboBox = false;                  
                }               
            }
        }

        private void ChangeCellToComboBox(int iRowIndex)
        {
            if (bIsComboBox == false)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgComboCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                dgComboCell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;

                dgComboCell.Items.Add("");   
                dgComboCell.Items.Add("ON");
                dgComboCell.Items.Add("OFF");

 datagridview.Rows[iRowIndex].Cells[datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex] = dgComboCell;
                bIsComboBox = true;
            }   
        }

            private void datagridview_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {  
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.FormattedValue != null)
            {
                var cell = this.datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                if (cell != null && e.FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty && !cell.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
                {
                    cell.Items[0] = e.FormattedValue;

                    if (this.datagridview.IsCurrentCellDirty)
                    {
                        this.datagridview.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                    }
                    cell.Value = e.FormattedValue;
                }
            }
        }

           private void datagridview_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {   
            if (e.ColumnIndex ==2)
            {
                NumericUpDown editingControl = this.datagridview.EditingControl as NumericUpDown;
                if (editingControl != null)
                {
                    editingControl.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler(myUpDownCtl_ValueChanged);
                }               
            }
        }

            private void datagridview_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (datagridview.CurrentCell == datagridview[2, 0])
            {
                ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;

                if (cb != null)
                {
                    cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= Cb_SelectedIndexChanged;

                    // Following line needed for initial setup.
                    cb.DropDownStyle = cb.SelectedIndex == 0 ? ComboBoxStyle.DropDown : ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                    cb.SelectedIndexChanged += Cb_SelectedIndexChanged;
                }
             }   
        }

        private void Cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
            cb.DropDownStyle = cb.SelectedIndex == 0 ? ComboBoxStyle.DropDown : ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            int selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
       //     MessageBox.Show("Selected Index = " + selectedIndex);
        }
```

Comment: The posted code is missing many parts and because of this, trying to replicate your problem is not possible with the currently posted code. You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just guessing… What’s in the combo boxes to begin with???? In addition from your statement: _”Now I select key text number to row[0]column[2], whenr I finish enter number and use "Enter"”_... sounds like you are “entering” a number into the combo box cell?… That’s not how combo boxes work. If what you type “matches” one of the items in the combo boxes collection of items, then it will display that value, however you cannot display an item in a combo box that does not exist in its collection.